# Unable to select a single check box in the admin grid

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid-layout

I'm working on magento 2.1. For deleting two or more rows from the admin grid, I'm unable to select the corresponding rows using the checkbox. If I clicked on a single check box, then all check boxes is getting checked.
[image]

Is this because of any JS issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast I found the issue myself. I was given a wrong value in the indexField. I corrected the same. And now it's working fine.

`<!--The list of columns-->
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">request_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>`

Comment: same issue i have set corrected value but not working

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have faced but after searching i found solution.

```
 <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
```

Never use **entity_id** as column name in grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my totalRecords was returning as 1, but I had over 200 items in the list. Hope this helps someone if they face the same issue